# Why do I get "value X is not a member of Y" error in this code?

Tags: java, scala, twitter, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4j for fetching trends from Twitter using the following code:

```
    val twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance
    val twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance
    twitterStream.addListener(simpleStatusListener) 
    val trends = twitter.getTrends
    println(trends.getName)
```

I tried different methods for getting trends but I keep getting the following error:

```
value getTrends is not a member of twitter4j.Twitter
```

Can someone point out what is wrong?

Comment: obviously that's because `getTrends` is [not defined/not publicly visible in twitter](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Twitter.html)

Comment: I know it is a interface but how do I define the method ?

Comment: @princessofpersion perhaps what you need is one of [those methods](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TrendsResources.html)(`Twitter` implements all of them), like `getAvailableTrends`?

Comment: Why do you assume twitter.getTrends() is a legal instruction?

Answer (score 1):

That method was [removed](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/commit/06dd4358aa4fb0bb09467545a1d976df23d15ea8) from `twitter4j` and subsequently from the examples. Take a look at other trends-related methods that are [currently supported](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/TwitterImpl.java#L1687).

The author has many other, up-to-date, examples [here](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/tree/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples).

Comment: I'm pointing to examples that are more up-to-date than the one OP is using.